# Detecting curves in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, detect, curve

I am just starting to use OpenCV to detect specific curves in an image. First, I want to verify if there is a curve, and next, I would like to identify the type of curve according to vertical or horizontal convex or concave curve. Is there an available function in OpenCV? If not, can you give me some ideas about how can I possibly write such a function? Thanks! By the way, I'm using C++.

Comment: What kind of images are you dealing with? What background do they have? If possible attach some pictures of your images.

Answer (score 6):

Template matching is not a robust way to solve this problem (its like looking at an object from a small pinhole) and edge detectors don't necessarily return you the true edges in the image; false edges such as those due to shadows are returned too. Further, you have to deal with the problem of incomplete edges and other problems that scales up with the complexity of the scene in your image.

The problem you posed, in general, is a very challenging one and, except for toy examples, there are no good solutions.

A rough attempt could be to first try to detect *plausible* edges using an edge detector (e.g. the canny edge detector suggested). Next, use RANSAC to try to fit a subset of the points in the detected edges to your curve model.

For e.g. let's say you are trying to detect a curve of the following form f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c. RANSAC will basically try to find from among the points in the detected edges, a subset of them that would best fit this curve model. To detect different curves, change f(x) accordingly and run RANSAC for each of them. You can then try to determine if the curve represented by f(x) really exists in your image using some heuristic applied to from the  points that were assigned to it by RANSAC (e.g. if too few points were fitted to the model it is likely that the curve is not there. But how to determine a good threshold for the number of points?). You model will get more complex when you have to account for allowable transformation such as rotation etc.

The problem with this approach is you are basically trying fit what you think should be in the image to the points and sometimes, even if what you are looking for is not there, it will return you the "best possible" fit. For e.g. you have a whole bunch of points detected from a concentric circle. If you try to detect straight lines from these points, RANSAC will return you the best fit line! In fact, it could give you many different lines from different runs depending on which points it selected during its random initialization stage.

For more details on how to use RANSAC on this sort of problem, have a look at [RANSAC for Dummies](http://old.vision.ece.ucsb.edu/~zuliani/Research/RANSAC/docs/RANSAC4Dummies.pdf) by [Marco Zuliani](http://old.vision.ece.ucsb.edu/~zuliani/index.shtml). He also has a nice [MATLAB toolbox](http://old.vision.ece.ucsb.edu/~zuliani/Code/Code.html) to accompany this tech report, which you can probably port to the language of your choice.

Unless you know what you background looks like, or if you are in control of it e.g. by forcing a clean background, this is a very difficult problem to solve.